# launching a coco2d OpenGL View from a viewcontroller

Tags: ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone

Normally, the coco2d OpenGL view is launched from the appdelegate.

Method1: luanching from appdelegate

```
- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
 {

  // Init the window
window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// Try to use CADisplayLink director
// if it fails (SDK < 3.1) use the default director
if( ! [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDisplayLink] )
    [CCDirector setDirectorType:kCCDirectorTypeDefault];


CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

// Init the View Controller
viewController = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
viewController.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

//
// Create the EAGLView manually
//  1. Create a RGB565 format. Alternative: RGBA8
//  2. depth format of 0 bit. Use 16 or 24 bit for 3d effects, like CCPageTurnTransition
//
//
EAGLView *glView = [EAGLView viewWithFrame:[window bounds]
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];

// attach the openglView to the director
[director setOpenGLView:glView];
```

but I need to  able to launch the OpenGL view from a viewcontroller
so, inside my viewcontroller's viewdidload function I did this

method2: launch from viewcontroller
      - (void)viewDidLoad
     {

```
 [super viewDidLoad];

self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

// Create an CCGLView with a RGB565 color buffer, and a depth buffer of 0-bits
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                        preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                sharegroup:nil
                             multiSampling:NO
                           numberOfSamples:0];

director_ = (CCDirectorIOS*) [CCDirector sharedDirector];


director_.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;

// Display FSP and SPF
[director_ setDisplayStats:YES];

// set FPS at 60
[director_ setAnimationInterval:1.0/60];

// attach the openglView to the director
[director_ setView:glView];

// for rotation and other messages
[director_ setDelegate:self];

// 2D projection
[director_ setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
// Run the intro Scene



[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

// and add the scene to the stack. The director will run it when it automatically when the view is displayed.
[director_ pushScene: [helloworld scene]];
```

method2 is not working I don't see any scene, nothing shows up.   so the question is how to make OpenGL View present from a viewcontroller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried as in the class reference [attachInView:](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/0.99.3/interface_c_c_director.html#af728734e51b9fb98075217ffddd65241) method?

It'be of the form

```
[director_ attachInView:self.view];
```

else you can do it by

```
[self.view addSubview:director_.view];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

since CCDirectorIOS inherits CCDirector class which in turn inherits uiviewcontroller class, and i am assuming you are using uinavigationcontroller, therefore just push the director_ class at the end viewdidload

[self.navigationController pushViewController:director_ animated:YES];